# Как можно создать форму для входа с логином и паролем без PHP/MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, авторизация

Нужно создать форму для входа только при помощи HTML и JavaScript. Больше ничего нельзя использовать.

Comment: Web SQL не подойдёт?

Comment: Думаю, подойдет. Спасибо!

Comment: Какие требования к этой форме входа? Потому что можно и на чистом HTML сделать форму из логина, пароля и кнопки "Войти". Это может считаться формой входа, хотя без серверной части она работать, конечно, не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту идею можно реализовать с помощью [Web SQL](https://habrahabr.ru/post/84654/)

Answer (score 0):

это какая-то глупая затея, вам все равно ж надо проверять правильность введенных данных, на чистом js можно конешно жестко поставить проверку пользователя - но это очень глупо.

Comment: Это просто студенческий проект, поэтому и затея глупая.

Comment: тогда на сабмите кнопки отлавливайте значения полей, сравниваете с конкретной захардкоженой парой в js и в случае если все верно переходите на страницу, в противном случае показываете сообщение что данные не верны и саму форму авторизации, на самом деле это очень просто

Comment: Если с Web SQL не выйдет, так и сделаю.